Calculating Ridge Weights / Augmented Synthetic Control
I am currently trying to recreate the results of the Kansas Tax Cut from Ben-Michael et al. (2021). Augmented Synthetic Control Method.
I need to do this in Stata (I know there is a written R command). While in general, I know how to calculate the ASMC weights (combination of ridge+scm weights, as in equation (17)) using the lambda resulting from the ridge regression, I fail to calculate the ridge weights (as in Figure 13). I would assume, that these weights are simply the coefficients of a ridge regression from all states on the state of kansas before the year of the intervention. I do this by making the columns the states 1-50, and appending the lagged outcomes. Where am I going wrong?
